# Angular 2 with utility js having require js

Tags: jquery, angular, requirejs

We have a application built with Require js, Jquery. Now we would like to add angular 2 to one of the screens in the application. I tried out few examples using angular2, its great and working fine.

Now I am planning to integrate that with our application. So as per the below link, I found we have to use system.js in angular2 instead of require.js
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5412

But in that case I have some utility js which I cant change as it used in various screens. The utility js has require syntax

```
define(['jquery','misc','utils','common','screenUtils'], 
    function(jQuery, misc,utils,common,screenUtils) { 
   //Public function goes here.
return publicFunctions;
}
);
```

Please advice in this case how will I add dependency to my new angular 2 component. I am new to angular2 and have no idea how to inject utility js with require.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'animate-app',
    templateUrl: 'ts-src/animate.tpl.html',
    host: {'class' : 'ng-animate page2Container'}
})
export class AnimateComponent{
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can configure your JS file into SystemJS. The loader supports different module formats like System, CommonJS and AMD.

Here is a sample:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    yourlib: 'path-to/lib.js'
  }
});
```

Then you will then be able import your lib this way:

```
import * as yourlib from 'yourlib';
```

or

```
import {test} as yourlib from 'yourlib';
```

See this plunkr as a sample (file lib.js, config.js and src/app.js): https://plnkr.co/edit/nRaO0c4Qmr3KUcFhVHbq?p=preview.